# #if (DEBUG) is not working in the customized base class libraries

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, .net-assembly

I create a Windows application in VS 2010 C#. It is a web crawler application and using the
N tier application structure (One Windows application and many class libraries in this 
project). Last week i implement a Log system in all projects for creating log text for 
solve performance issues. But now i want to disable this log functions in Release Mode.

I googled and get a example from [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/321120/Csharp-Determining-whether-the-current-build-mode). Please see my code below.

```
public class ModeDetector
{
    public virtual bool IsDebug
    {
        get
        {
            bool isDebug = false;

            #if (DEBUG)
            isDebug = true;
            #else
            isDebug = false;
            #endif

            return isDebug;
        }
    }

    public bool IsRelease
    {
        get { return !IsDebug; }
    }
}
```

I create this class in my base class library. for get this class for all reference 
projects. I call this method in my Windows application. like

```
if (new Sun.lib.ModeDetector().IsDebug)
            MessageBox.Show("Debug Mode");
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Release Mode");
```

and change my project Build Configuration to " Release " . But this code is always shows the " Debug Mode " message. But when i create this class in my windows application it's works fine. But i am too worry about to create this class in every project.

Please advise me what is the best practices to determine a project(s) is work debug or release mode. How can i use this class in entire project.

**Edits :**

I refer the class library in the Debug bug folder of class library project.

my class libraries and win forms applications are lie on the same solutions.

Comment: Why don´t you just use the pragma condition instead of implementing your own class?

#if (DEBUG) MessageBox.Show("Debug Mode"); #

Comment: Sounds to me you are using the debug build of this library from the release build of your project.  This can only work when the library is in the same solution and you change the solution's configuration.

Comment: Thanks for your valueable reply. I use the class library in same solution. But i reference this class library in bin/Debug/MyClasslib.dll. This is the reason for this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you  [Marcus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1376691/marcus). I follow your instruction and rewrite my code like:

```
#if (DEBUG) 

    MessageBox.Show("Debug Mode");

#else

    MessageBox.Show("Release Mode");

#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

The `DEBUG` flag is set per library, not per solution. You will need to set (or remove) that flag in every library you use in your solution.

Comment: Thanks for your valueable reply.

Comment: @RageshPuthiyedath thank you for your appreciation. If an answer has helped you, please upvote, or mark as answer. This is the StackOverflow-way of saying "Thank you". See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you trying to reinvent conditional attributes similar to what used in `Debug.XXXX` methods. [Conditional attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664622%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) allow to make method calls no-op if given symbol is not defined.

I.e. look at [Debug.Write](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/848f20dy.aspx) method that is tracing in debug build (when `DEBUG` is defined) and no-op in release:

```
[ConditionalAttribute("DEBUG")]
public static void Write(Object value)
```

Note that you'll not be able to implement virtual function you want as methods with conditional attributes will be called or not depending on conditional symbol, but code inside of the method will not vary.

`#if` changes what code will be compiled. Compiled DLL will have only one branch (matching the condition).

You need to reference matching libraries in release and debug builds. If you are using single solution for all your projects it will be setup automatically, if you have separate solutions I believe you'll need to edit ".csproj" files manually to include different versions of your library depending on defines.